# Finding the turning point (inflection point) of COVID-19 infections using inflection package

Tags: r

I am not sure if I have done my inflection point calculation correctly. Based on lab confirmed cumulative case data in the epicenter of the current epidemic, we have tried to identify the inflection point. I used the `inflection` package and calculated the inflection point as "08 Feb 2020". I have also tried to calculate the first and second directives as estimated increase each and changing rate.

Are those results from the following graphs consistent?

```r
df<-structure(list(date = structure(c(18277, 18278, 18279, 18280, 
18281, 18282, 18283, 18284, 18285, 18286, 18287, 18288, 18289, 
18290, 18291, 18292, 18293, 18294, 18295, 18296, 18297, 18298, 
18299, 18300, 18301, 18302, 18303, 18304, 18305, 18306, 18307), 
class = "Date"), 
cases = c(45, 62, 121, 198, 258, 363, 425, 
        495, 572, 618, 698, 1590, 1905, 2261, 2639, 3125, 4109, 5142, 
        6384, 8351, 10117, 11618, 13603, 14982, 16903, 18454, 19558, 
       20630, 21960, 22961, 23621)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -31L))
xlb_0<- structure(c(18281, 18285, 18289, 18293, 
                    18297, 18301, 18305,   
                    18309), class = "Date")
library(tidyverse)
# Smooth cumulative cases over time 
df$x = as.numeric(df$date)
fit_1<- loess(cases ~ x, span = 1/3, data = df) 
df$case_sm <-fit_1$fitted 

# use inflection to obtain inflection point
library(inflection)
guai_0 <- check_curve(df$x, df$case_sm)
check_curve(df$x, df$cases)
#> $ctype
#> [1] "convex_concave"
#> 
#> $index
#> [1] 0
guai_1 <- bese(df$x, df$cases, guai_0$index)
structure(guai_1$iplast, class = "Date")
#> [1] "2020-02-08"

# Plot cumulativew numbers of cases 
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = cases ))+
  geom_line(aes(y = case_sm), color = "red") +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = guai_1$iplast) + 
  labs(y = "Cumulative lab confirmed infections")
```

[image]

```r
# Daily new cases (first derivative) and changing rate (second derivative)
df$dt1 = c(0, diff(df$case_sm)/diff(df$x))
fit_2<- loess(dt1 ~ x, span = 1/3, data = df) 
df$change_sm <-fit_2$fitted 
df$dt2 <- c(NA, diff(df$change_sm)/diff(df$x)) 

df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = dt1))+
  geom_line(aes(y = dt1, 
                color = "Estimated number of new cases")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = dt2*2, color = "Changing rate")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = dt2*2, color = "Changing rate"))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = guai_1$iplast) + 
  labs(y = "Estimatede number of new cases") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = xlb_0, 
               date_labels = "%b%d") + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
#> Warning: Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Although, the question is interesting I am not sure if this is the right platform for it because to answer these questions (especially 2nd) one requires domain knowledge more than programming language.

Comment: I kind of felt the same when I prepared the question. I have removed the second question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Shouldn't the inflection point of the cumulative density distribution coincide with the *extremum* (maximum) of the density function? In other words, at the inflection point of the cumulative density, the first derivative of the density (i.e. the second derivative of the cumulative density) should be zero. Unless I misunderstood, that doesn't seem to be the case when comparing both plots. Also: You mention a second derivative curve in black, but the second plot shows a red and cyan curve.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks a lot. I am confused with the results too. I removed incorrect description of colors. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was gonna write a comment, but I was pushing the character limit.

I am not familiar with the `inflection` package so I am not one to judge if the `2020-02-08` is the true inflection. However, I will say this is difficult to answer with R because R is not necessarily good at calculating derivatives. If you had an estimated line equation - then you could potentially use this to plot first and second derivatives. Calculating rough delta's by doing the difference in `(Y_n+1-Y_n)/(X_n+1-X_n)` is never optimal because a [derivate](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_(mathematics)) in theory is the delta of two points infinitesimally close to each other. You fundamentally cannot get a great estimate of the derivative. You can even see this because you are forced to shift this estimate to either `n` or `n+1`. Furthermore,  you would expect the inflection point of `x_0` to be a local min/max in the first derivative and equal to zero in the second derivative. So I don't think your second plot helps. But this could just be due to the delta's calculated.

What I would do is first fit your data to some type of model.
In this example I'm going to use the package `dr4pl` to model your data to the 4 parameter logistic model.
Since the function of the 4 parameter model is well known, I can write what the first and second derivative functions should be, then plot those values using `stat_function` in the `ggplot2` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dr4pl)
df<-structure(list(date = structure(c(18277, 18278, 18279, 18280, 
                                      18281, 18282, 18283, 18284, 18285, 18286, 18287, 18288, 18289, 
                                      18290, 18291, 18292, 18293, 18294, 18295, 18296, 18297, 18298, 
                                      18299, 18300, 18301, 18302, 18303, 18304, 18305, 18306, 18307), 
                                    class = "Date"), 
                   cases = c(45, 62, 121, 198, 258, 363, 425, 
                             495, 572, 618, 698, 1590, 1905, 2261, 2639, 3125, 4109, 5142, 
                             6384, 8351, 10117, 11618, 13603, 14982, 16903, 18454, 19558, 
                             20630, 21960, 22961, 23621)), 
              class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -31L))
xlb_0<- structure(c(18281, 18285, 18289, 18293, 
                    18297, 18301, 18305,   
                    18309), class = "Date")

df$dat_as_num <- as.numeric(df$date)

dr4pl_obj <- dr4pl(cases~dat_as_num, data = df, init.parm = c(30000, 18300, 2, 0))
#first derivative derivation
d1_dr4pl <- function(x, theta, scale = F){
  if (any(is.na(theta))) {
    stop("One of the parameter values is NA.")
  }
  if (theta[2] <= 0) {
    stop("An IC50 estimate should always be positive.")
  }
  f <- -theta[3]*((theta[4]-theta[1])/((1+(x/theta[2])^theta[3])^2))*((x/theta[2])^(theta[3]-1))
  if(scale) {
    f <- scales::rescale(x = f, to = c(theta[4],theta[1]))
  }
  return(f)
}
#Second derivative derivation
d2_dr4pl <- function(x, theta, scale = F){
  if (any(is.na(theta))) {
    stop("One of the parameter values is NA.")
  }
  if (theta[2] <= 0) {
    stop("An IC50 estimate should always be positive.")
  }
  f <- 2*((theta[3]*(x/theta[2])^(theta[3]-1))^2)*((theta[4]-theta[1])/((1+(x/theta[2])^(theta[3]))^3))-theta[3]*(theta[3]-1)*((x/theta[2])^(theta[3]-2))*((theta[4]-theta[1])/((1+(x/theta[2])^theta[3])^2))
  if(scale) {
    f <- scales::rescale(x = f, to = c(theta[4],theta[1]))
    f <- f - f[1]
  }
  return(f)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = dat_as_num)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]geom_point(aes(y = cases), color = "grey", alpha = .6, size = 5) +
  stat_function(fun = d1_dr4pl, args = list(theta = dr4pl_obj$parameters, scale = T), color = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = d2_dr4pl, args = list(theta = dr4pl_obj$parameters, scale = T), color = "blue") +
  stat_function(fun = dr4pl::MeanResponse, args = list(theta = dr4pl_obj$parameters), color = "gold") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = dr4pl_obj$parameters[2], linetype = "dotted") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: dr4pl fitted curve in yellow, "scaled" first derivative in red, "scaled" second derivative in blue]

As you can see, the inflection point, which is the IC50 value (theta 2) of the 4 parameter logistic model, lines up well when we approach it this way.

```
summary(dr4pl_obj)
#$call
#dr4pl.formula(formula = cases ~ dat_as_num, data = df, init.parm = c(30000, 18300, 2, 0))
#
#$coefficients
#               Estimate       StdErr       2.5 %      97.5 %
#Upper limit 25750.61451 4.301008e-05 25750.59681 25750.63221
#Log10(IC50) 18298.75347 4.301008e-09 18298.67889 18298.82806
#Slope        5154.35449 4.301008e-05  5154.33678  5154.37219
#Lower limit    58.48732 4.301008e-05    58.46962    58.50503
#
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "summary.dr4pl"
```

Furthermore, using `dr4pl`, it says the IC50 value is roughly `18298.8`, which is late `2020-02-06`. Not too far off from the `inflection` value. I'm sure there may be a better model to use than the 4pl, but it was just the one that I knew I could write first and second derivatives for the purposes of answering this question.

I'm sure other coding languages are more specialized when it comes to derivatives, and can even calculate them for you so long as you start with an initial function. I think one of these languages is mathematica.

A **disclaimer**, I ended up scaling the first and second derivatives so that they could be plotted together. Their actual values are much larger than shown here.

Comment: No problem. I will say the one disadvantage to using this method is if you cannot find a function that models your data well. Otherwise, as Maurits pointed out, using `geom_smooth` on `calc_d` might be a good way to visualize the derivatives without an equation.

Answer (score 1):

A very quick back-of-the-envelope plot based on your data shows

```
calc_d <- function(x) c(0, diff(x))
df %>%
    mutate(
        first_deriv_cases = calc_d(cases),
        second_deriv_cases = calc_d(calc_d(cases))) %>%
    pivot_longer(-date) %>%
    ggplot(aes(date, value)) +
        geom_line() +
        facet_wrap(~name, scale = "free_y", ncol = 1) +
        geom_smooth()
```

[image]

So the inflection point at 8 February is consistent with the first derivative (i.e. the density function) having a maximum at that point.